# Pytorch: non-positive stride is not supported

Tags: python, pytorch

I have some MRI scans, where each scan is a set of 31 RGB images. The dimensions of the input data are (Channels, Depth, Height, Width). The images are png, and each scan is a folder containing its 31 images.

I created a custom Dataset class:

```
class TrainImages(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):
        self.annotations = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.annotations)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, str(self.annotations.iloc[index, 0]).zfill(5))
        image = torch.from_numpy(np.array([np.array(Image.open(os.path.join(str(img_path),"rgb-"+str(i)+".png"))) for i in range(31)]).transpose(3,0,1,2).astype(np.float32))
        y_label = torch.tensor(int(self.annotations.iloc[index, 1]))
        
        return (image, y_label)
```

Then, I created a small 3D CNN class:

```
class CNN2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN2, self).__init__()        
        self.conv_layer1 = self._conv_layer(3, 12)


    def _conv_layer(self, in_c, out_c, conv_kernel_size=3, padding=0):
        layer = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv3d(in_c, out_c, conv_kernel_size, padding),
        )
        
        return layer
    
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv_layer1(x)
        
        return out
```

Then, I tried to feed one scan into the CNN2 object:

```
    x=torch.unsqueeze(dataset[0][0], 0)
    x.shape #torch.Size([1, 3, 31, 512, 512])
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    data = x.to(device)
    model = CNN2().to(device)
    model(x)
```

But it produces this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-c89306854a22> in <module>
      1 model = CNN_test().to(device)
----> 2 model(x)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

<ipython-input-22-ac66ca7a2459> in forward(self, x)
     14 
     15     def forward(self, x):
---> 16         out = self.conv_layer1(x)
     17 
     18         return out

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
    115     def forward(self, input):
    116         for module in self:
--> 117             input = module(input)
    118         return input
    119 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in forward(self, input)
    571                             self.dilation, self.groups)
    572         return F.conv3d(input, self.weight, self.bias, self.stride,
--> 573                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    574 
    575 

RuntimeError: non-positive stride is not supported
```

However, when I just create a `Conv3D` object and pass the same scan in, no error results:

```
x=torch.unsqueeze(dataset[0][0], 0)
m=nn.Conv3d(3,12,3)
out=m(x)
```

I think the error might have to do with the dimensions of the input data, but I don't understand what "non-positive stride" means. I'm also confused why no error occurs when I just pass the data into a `Conv3D` object, but an error occurs when I pass the same data into an instance of the `CNN` class that does the same thing.

Comment: Why do you call it 4-D? It seems to be a set of rgb values of a 3-D volume: (x,y,z, value)

Comment: It may be giving error on 0 values in the data. Or is it possible that negative values have come after 'transform'? (Although default for transform is None)

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right, it is a set of rgb values of 3D volume. Thank you, I'll edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with your input shape, it has to do with your layer initialization. You have essentially defined your 3D convolution with this line:

```
nn.Conv3d(in_c, out_c, conv_kernel_size, padding)
```

The issue is `nn.Conv3d` function head is the following:

> `torch.nn.Conv3d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1, groups=1, bias=True, padding_mode='zeros', device=None, dtype=None)`

Notice how `stride` is placed before `padding`. In your code, variable `padding` ends up being assigned to the `stride` argument.

To solve the issue, you can specify the argument name with a keyword argument, *i.e.* `padding=padding`. This disambiguates the issue with positional arguments `stride` and `padding`.

```
class CNN2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN2, self).__init__()        
        self.conv_layer1 = self._conv_layer(3, 12)

    def _conv_layer(self, in_c, out_c, conv_kernel_size=3, padding=0):
        layer = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv3d(in_c, out_c, conv_kernel_size, padding=padding))
        return layer
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv_layer1(x)
        return out
```